# Is this evidence of a GAE memory leak?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memory-leaks, jdo, visualvm

Depending on the setting of autocreateDatastoreTxns, I get a memory leak, with
one instance of each of the classes below created for each query (a read). 
i.e. 100 queries creates 100 instances of each of the classes below (with the
exception of the DatastoreServiceConfig, which gets 2 instances per query).

I've found this using the Java VisualVM profiler in the development environment. The reason I'm doing this
is that in production, our instance heap sizes keep growing (usually getting too large
after 10-20 thousand requests) finally causing slow responses and instance restarts.
I don't know if this is the cause, but it's the first leak I've been able to identify so far.

// Leaks with datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns=false

```
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManager
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.KeyRegistry
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.EmualtedXARResource
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection
```

// Leaks with datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns=true

```
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceConfig  // 2 instances per query
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManager
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo. DatastoreJDOTransation
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreXARResource
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreProperty
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyRegistry
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.TransactionStackImpl$ThreadLocalTransactionStack$StaticMember
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.TransactionStackImpl
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.RuntimeExceptionWrapperingDatastoreService
```

Here is my code:

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
try {
    account = pm.detachCopy(pm.getObjectById(Account.class, accountKey));
} catch (javax.jdo.JDOObjectNotFoundException ex) {
    account = null;
} finally {
    pm.close();
}
```

Any ideas/thoughts?  Is this a real memory leak in Google AppEngine, or is it just fact of life for the development environment, or maybe my own error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The development appserver is intended to simulate the semantics of the real appserver, so that you can develop with reasonable fidelity. That doesn't include memory behavior, particularly with regard to the datastore. The dev server tends to keep things in memory in ways that the real appserver doesn't. Profiling the development server can still be useful for sorting out leaks on the app side, but isn't going to give you much guidance about leaks that may be on the appserver side. We do watch out for those, though. And heaps do fragment over time.

Some apps, by the nature of their usage and data access patterns, benefit from larger front-end instances. Those cost more, so you have to test and weight the benefit against the added cost.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid that'd be the case regarding production vs development for memory profiling...  Yes, we've moved to F2 instance because the extra memory helps the instances last a bit longer, but the memory leak seems to be quite substantial so it's only a small stop-gap.

Comment: I will continue looking for leaks within our own code, but do you have any hints about where to look from other experience with GAE instance heaps growing so much? I haven't found any discussions about it anywhere - is it rare?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen, there is a JDO memory leak on production AppEngine.

This causes increased latency in instances over time. This problem has been around for a while with no apparent solution being offered officially, so below is a quick solution of a PMF class that I have been using in production systems for more than a year now, and which solved the problem of increased latency (memory usage still grows but not as fast).

```
import javax.jdo.JDOHelper;
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory;

public final class PMF {

    private static final int RECYCLE_POINT = 5000;
    private static final int BUFFER_ZONE = RECYCLE_POINT / 10;
    private static int pmfcount = 1;
    private static int marker = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    private static PersistenceManagerFactory pmfInstancePrevious = null;
    private static PersistenceManagerFactory pmfInstance = JDOHelper
            .getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

    private PMF() {
    }

    public static PersistenceManagerFactory get() {
        int icount = pmfcount;
        if (icount % RECYCLE_POINT == 0) {
            synchronized (pmfInstance) {
                pmfInstancePrevious = pmfInstance;
                marker = icount;
                pmfInstance = JDOHelper
                    .getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional");
            }
        }
        if(marker+BUFFER_ZONE == icount) {
            if (null != pmfInstancePrevious) pmfInstancePrevious.close();
        }
        pmfcount++;
        return pmfInstance;
    }
}
```

The code is thread safe (synchronised) and can be used with multi-threaded instances and without any other changes to your JDO code.

You can tweak the RECYCLE_POINT depending on your usage of PMF.get() but i found 5000 calls to be a good point to get a new instance.

The BUFFER_ZONE is also important if you are getting any messages that PMF was closed while being used. This means that you are keeping a handle around of PersistenceManagerFactory or doing very long lived requests. You should instead use PMF.get() with every start of a request (or even multiple times in each request). Increase the BUFFER_ZONE if you want to keep the previous PMF instance around for longer but always a fraction of RECYCLE_POINT.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a GAE leak. It could also be a bug in your code. The only way to distinguish the cases is to track down the actual cause of the (probable) leak.

I should add that the leak could be in another part of your code; e.g. if you are using a persistence manager somewhere else.  FWIW, the code in your question looks OK to me ...